# Indentation in Mathematica notebook

Tags: notebooks

since a few days I have the problem that in my .nb programs whenever I want to edit something auto-indentation appears. While the code lines were all left-aligned in the saved version of the notebookt, now when I want to edit something there is an indent in the new line.

Where does this come from? I don't remember that I had changed something.

Comment: `Mathematica | Preferences... | Advanced | Open Option Inspector | Selected Notebook | Private Editing Options | AutoIndent | False`